# Which is the best method to do pagination so that load on server is minimum

Tags: pagination, operation

I have done a bit of research on pagination and from what i have read there are 2 contradictory solutions of doing it

1. Load a small set of data from the database each time a user clicks next
     Problem - Suppose there are a million rows that meet any WHERE conditions. That means a million rows are retrieved, stored, filesorted, then most of them are discarded and only 20 retrieved. If the user clicks the "next" button the same process happens again, only a different 20 are retrieved.(ref - **http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/24/four-ways-to-optimize-paginated-displays/**)
2. Load all the data form the database and cache it...This has few problems too mentioned here - **http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t63849.html**

So i know i will have to use a hybrid of both..however the question boils down to - Which operation is more expensive -
   making repeated queries in database for small chunks of data
                       or
   transferring a large result set over the network

Answer (score 0):

My company has exactly this situation, and we've chosen a bit of a hybrid.  Our data is tabular, so we send it via AJAX to [datatables](http://www.datatables.net)  This allows for good UI formatting, sorting, filtering, and show/hide of columns.  Datatables has a great solution that will "queue ahead" called "pipelining" that will grab a quantity of data ahead of the user's action (in our case, up to 5 times the records they request) then page through without requests until it runs out of data.  It's EXTREMELY easy to implement with Datatables, but I suspect a similar solution would not be difficult if you had to write it by hand using jQuery's AJAX functionality.

I tried doing a full load and cache on a 1.5 million record database and it was a trainwreck.  The client almost dumped me because they got mad it was so slow.  After a solid overnight of AJAX goodness, the client was happy once again.  But best never to get to that point.

Good Luck.